# Passing a collection to print, to print with a separator in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, formatting, arguments, parameter-passing, keyword-argument

In Python 3, you can print a bunch of `objects*` with a variable number of objects as the first bunch of args:

For example:

```
print(192,168,178,42,sep=".")
```

Or for example:

```
print("09","03","2018",sep="-")
```

But like let's say I have a collection of `[192,168,178,42]` and I want to pass that to printed with a separator...how do I "unbox it into formal arguments" (and I'm using the term loosely) into arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `*` unpacking operator:

```
print(*[192,168,178,42],sep=".")
```

or with a variable:

```
mylist = [192,168,178,42]
print(*mylist, sep=".")
```

Output:

```
192.168.178.42
```

See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/) for more details on packing/unpacking in Python.

Comment: FTW there is also a unpack dict opertator `**`

Comment: @leeand00 Yes, but it only works for keyword args, not normal positional args. If you try to unpack a `dict` with `*`, it will unpack the keys.